# Changing number decimal separator for a specific program (EZ-builder)

Tags: regional-settings

I just installed EZ-builder for the EZ-robot. When trying to start the program I get this error message:

[image: Picture of the error message]

> Error
>
> This computer culture has the Number Decimal Seperator set to a ','. This
> setting needs to be a Period '.' for all EZ-Robot software to work.

The release notes http://www.ez-robot.com/Community/Forum/posts.aspx?threadId=2806 says that I need to change my windows decimal separator for it to work. The problem is that as a swedish user I need to have a comma as a decimal separator for everything else that I do on my computer, and changing it just for the sake of one program seems unnecessary.

My question is if there's any way to isolate the Number Decimal Separator for a specific program so that I can change it for just EZ-builder?

Answer (score 0):

Since I am having the same problem in another application, I couldnot still solve this problem. But the following may work on your project. For Win10:

Open > "Time and language" settings from the control panel. Click "Language". > "Administrator language settings". Press the "Additional settings" button on the "Formats" tab. The decimal symbol should be "," Change it to "."

Good luck!

Comment: “The problem is that … I need to have a comma as a decimal separator for everything else that I do on my computer, …. / My question is if there’s any way to isolate the Number Decimal Separator for a specific program so that I can change it for just EZ-builder?”  This answer changes the settings for the whole system.